# Android button designations - what do they actually mean?

Tags: android, button, dialog

This is just a simple question of semantics, but I can't find the answer anywhere! We have BUTTON_POSITIVE, BUTTON_NEGATIVE and BUTTON_NEUTRAL in dialogs, but what exactly is the meaning of positive, negative and neutral buttons?

If I have a Yes/No alert dialog, and I want No to be the default, which is which? Or maybe the concept of a default button doesn't apply to Android. (In Visual C++ for example on a PC, the default button is the one that is activated if you hit return.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Note: You can only add one of each button type to the AlertDialog. That is, you cannot have more than one "positive" button. This limits the number of possible buttons to three: positive, neutral, and negative. **These names are technically irrelevant to the actual functionality of your buttons, but should help you keep track of which one does what.**

You define which button has which function and name.

Example:

```
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                MyActivity.this.finish();
           }
       })
```

The positive button could be set to "No" if you really wanted to. The link shows a more detailed code example.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [Adding Buttons in the UI guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingButtons) it states

> "These names are technically irrelevant to the actual functionality of
>   your buttons, but should help you keep track of which one does what."

So you could create an onCLickListener that cancels your action against a button and set it as the postive button - it'd just be confusing to someone reading the code.

---

Also, yep, there's no concept of a default button as so many of the devices that an Android app target have no keyboard. You could highlight one button differently so as to lead a user towards it. Also, you could override onKey in your Dialog and listen for [KeyCode_Enter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_ENTER) so that for devices that do have a hardware keyboard you can behave appropriately

Comment: +1 from me too. Sorry I can't mark two posts as answers! Plus the answer to the default button question. Many thanks